# Поиск в коллекции ArrayList

Tags: java

Есть коллекция:

```
List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();
```

В ней хранятся продукты с полями: `name, price, weight`.

Как организовать поиск определенного продукта, к примеру, по имени?

То есть, пользователь вводит имя, а ему возвращается соответствующий объект с полями: `name, price, weight`.

Comment: Перебрать все элементы в цикле, сравнивая поле `name` с заданным значением.

Comment: Вы очень помогли. Спасибо!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поиск по имени - `name`:

```
 products
    .stream()
    .filter(s -> s.getName().equals(name))
    .findFirst()
    .orElse("такого имени нет")
```

Comment: А зачем давать подобный ответ? Понятно же, что автор новичок. А вы такую задачу решаете с помощью стримов, которые автор врядли знает. А следовательно Ваш ответ будет для него не очень полезным.

Comment: Уж если даете ответ, то постарайтесь максимально помочь автору. Иначе не тратьте свое время.

Comment: @notaProgrammer учту, не буду на такие вопросы больше давать ответов